# Verilog + FPGA: If statement for switch

Tags: verilog, fpga

This is my code to control a RC Servo Motor. The code basically turns the 50MHz frequency to 1KHz.

I am using one of the switches on the FPGA to control the motor. Until the switch is on, none of the program should run.
But that doesn't seem to be happening. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. It's probably a very silly mistake.

```
module servo(clk,rst,clk_out,switch);
  input clk,rst,switch;
  output reg clk_out;
  reg [15:0] counter;

  always @(posedge clk or posedge rst or posedge switch)
    if (switch) begin
     if(rst) begin
       counter <=16'd0;
       clk_out <= 1'b0;
     end
     else if(counter==16'd25000) begin
       counter <=16'd0;
       clk_out <= ~clk_out;
     end
     else begin
       counter<=counter+1;
     end
   end
endmodule
```

Also I tried changing the duty cycle so the motor rotates faster, but this doesn't seem to be working.

```
module servo (clk,rst,clk_out,switch);
input clk,rst,switch;
output reg clk_out;
reg [15:0] counter;
always @(posedge clk or posedge rst)

if(rst)
begin
counter<=16'd0;
clk_out <= 1'b0;
end

else if (switch)

begin
  if(counter==16'd12500)
   begin
  clk_out <= 1'b1;
  counter<=counter+1;
   end
else
if(counter==16'd50000)
  begin
counter <= 16'd0;
clk_out <= 1'b0;
  end
else
  begin
counter<=counter+1;
  end
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my cut at it - I haven't simulated it, so beware!

```
module servo(clk,rst,clk_out,switch);
input clk,rst,switch;
output reg clk_out;
reg [15:0] counter;

// clocked blocks should only have the clock and maybe a reset
// in the sensitivity list
always @(posedge clk or posedge rst) begin
    if(rst) begin
        counter <=16'd0;
        clk_out <= 1'b0;
    end
    else if (switch) begin  // 'switch' used as an enable
        if(counter==16'd25000) begin
            counter <=16'd0;
            clk_out <= ~clk_out;
        end
        else begin
            counter<=counter+1;
        end
    end
    else begin
        counter <= 16'd0;
    end
end
endmodule
```

First thing I did was to remove the entry for `switch` in the sensitivity list - for synchronous logic, there should only be a clock and maybe a reset here.

The reset clause for the logic should be first, so I moved the test for `switch` using it as an enable signal in the main body of the always block. The counter will only run now if `switch` is high.

Comment: Yes I tried doing something like this but the counter would keep incrementing. I have a question: say the counter value is currently 1 and switch is high. Thus it will skip the "if(counter==16'd25000)" bit and go straight to incrementing the counter by 1. and then go back to the beginning of the loop. So what is the need of the end bit: else begin counter <= 16'd0; end

Comment: NB: Implying Set Reset flip-flops have 3 edge sensitive signals in the sensitivity list.

Comment: It's not really needed, I suppose.

Comment: @user1847610 so when you disable it, then turn it back on it starts from the beginning.

Comment: Hope I'm not pushing it too much but I'd be very grateful if you could help me with altering the duty cycle.
I've added it to my question.